# PySDL2: Creating a borderless window

Tags: python, borderless, pysdl2

I've been trying to find how I might create a borderless window (One not created using the typical windows border) in PySDL2.

I've looked at what resources I could find online, but haven't been able to pinpoint anything that would tell me how to accomplish this, despite it being **apparently possible**.

---

**Research:**

1. [This link](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/helloworld.html#window-creation-and-image-loading) states that in most cases you have a border and title bar around your window, but never went into any more detail as to how to manipulate it.
2. I looked at some [API references for SDL's Window](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_window.html#window-routines-to-manage-on-screen-windows), and did not see that borders could be manipulated at all. (Not stated that they couldn't be, just no mention)

---

Despite not finding anything PySDL2 related, I did find [at this link](https://pythonhosted.org/pysdl2-cffi/SDL.html) that:

```
sdl.setWindowBordered(window, bordered)
Sets the border state of a window.
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get this to work within [my simple example script](http://pastebin.com/V3aDk06U).

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Updated my answer to use sdl2.ext...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the flag: `SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS`.

Full example:

```
import sys
import sdl2.ext

sdl2.ext.init()

window = sdl2.ext.Window("Hello World!", size=(640, 480), flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS)
window.show()

processor = sdl2.ext.TestEventProcessor()
processor.run(window)
```

Modifying your script slightly we get:

```
import sys
import sdl2.ext

def run():
    sdl2.ext.init()
    W = sdl2.ext.Window("Default",size=(400,300), flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS)
    W.show()
    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        W.refresh()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Comment: hey, this seems to work! Thanks. I just wanted to know why nothing appeared at all. I was sort of expecting a borderless block of sorts. I can see the outline when I hover over my open icon of IDLE, but that's all. Do I need to fill the Window with something first?

Comment: @Owatch: The window is just black by default, if that's what you mean. You can draw stuff in it though, and that will not make it just black.

Comment: Well, it was actually completely transparent. (No background at all). But I have managed to add one now, using SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem, and an example from the tutorial! Is it possible to build my own Window type? As in, add a Close and Minimize button to the Window myself?

Comment: @Owatch: I believe you can create the buttons yourself and call the appropriate SDL events when they get clicked. But this is kind of a different question together...